# How to search file ending with pattern in a directory using Perl script

Tags: perl

I have to search a particular csv file ending with a variable "$runVar".csv in a folder. This should be the pattern : `anything <runVar>.csv`. I have to attach the output of this search and mail it.
please help. I tried mailing thing with a example file in shell using mutt. please confirm it will work in perl too?

Comment: It's far from clear what you want to do. Are you searching the file name or the file contents? Are you looking for `$runVar.csv`, `"$runVar".csv`, `<runVar>.csv`, or the *contents* of variable `runVar` followed by `.csv`?

Comment: i did not understand what do you exacly want, are you searching for a file that has a name "$runVar.csv" in some folder and if you find it, you have to send an email ?

Comment: Hi borodin, I am not looking for the contents of the file, actually i have this variable named runVar in my script & that variable will return me  a numerical value, and now i want to search a file (whose name) is ending with that runVar.csv, so i said there can be anything ahead in that name. To be more clear ill give you example: i want to search this file "DA_Mismatch_Count-RunId_1595.csv" where this numerical value  would be returned from runVar

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to look for a file with a name of "anything$runVar.csv", and then do something with that file. Here's an example of how to do that. If a file is found, it'll open it and print the contents.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $run_var = 1822;

my $rx = qr/(?<!\d)$run_var\.csv/;

my $dir = ".";

opendir my $dh, $dir or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir($dh)){

    if ($file =~ $rx){
        open my $fh, '<', $file
          or die $!;

        for my $line (<$fh>){
            chomp $line;
            print "$line\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't put capital letters in Perl lexical identifiers. `$run_var` is much more readable, especially for those whose first language isn't English

This is very easily done with `glob`

```
my @matches = glob "*$run_var.csv";
```

You will have to add the directory that you want to search to the beginning of the pattern string, or you can `chdir` there before you call `glob`